# How can I give my Flask App in GCP access to an external Network?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Flask app that is hosted in the Google App Engine. It wants to establish a TCP connection to a server on my local network to send data to the app. Unfortunately, my app can't connect to the server just like that because the IP address of the server is not public.

Unfortunately, I can't find a solution here. Can anyone give me a hint what I need to be able to connect to my network?

On the one hand it would be easier to make the IP address publicly available, but I really want to avoid that.

I would be glad about any help.

Comment: You need to create a VPN between your Google Cloud VPC and your private server. Then add a serverless VPC connector to App Engine to route private traffic through it.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Please consider posting your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a VPN between your Google Cloud VPC and your private server. Then add a [serverless VPC connector to App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/connecting-vpc) to route private traffic through it.